# Python - Error 500 when importing code from other scripts

Tags: python, python-import

I have a very strange problem.
When I run this script from the linux command line `python scriptname.py`, everything works fine. When I request it via the browser, it gives me Internal Error 500

I am importing a script trainstate.py which is in the same directory of the script I am running. I have also placed an empty file `__init__.py` with 777 rights in the directory

N.B. any script doing standard imports (e.g. `import os`) works fine via the browser

```
from trainstate import *

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

st = TrainState(784)
print st.get_state()
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: things you can do : 1) use `cgitb.enable()` 2) check `sys.path` 3) use `try: ... import ...... except ImportError: ...` to see what is going on 4) or use a wsgi framework with debugging capabilities.

Comment: @thkang from command line it doesn't give any problem, but with the browser it always outputs internal error 500 when the line `from trainstate import *` is there, so I am not sure how I can debug it. I cannot use the browser output, as it's always internal error 500

Comment: @thkang I just wrote a script to loop on `sys.path` and the finding is weird: if I call the script from the command line sys.path includes my current directory, if I call it from the browser the current directory is not in sys.path - any explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after your additional comments, I'd like to elaborate.

you might be using some cgi back-end that is not python's reference cgi/http/wsgi implementation. Instead, that back-end(be it apache, iis, whatever) might embed a python interpreter to run your python cgi scripts.

one of the most common problems that I have encountered in this setup is handling import paths. consider following scenario:

1. I have foo.py and bar.py in same directory.
2. foo.py is the cgi entry point.
3. foo.py imports bar.py -- `import bar` to do something.
4. somehow import fails.
5. which is very frustrating since we have no option but to stare at ugly bold **500** message.

this is, because the directroy of foo.py is not included in pythonpath, unlike when you run foo.py from commandline. to fix this, you can add its path to `sys.path`.

so, the solution would be:

```
import os
import sys
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, current_path)

... rest of the script
```

well, if you have your trainstate.py in some separate folder you have to add path to that folder in `sys.path`.

Comment: Thanks thkang! I solved it in that way! By the way, are you suggesting I should configure a different back-end? I am currently using the default configuration of my virtual server. Can you provide some easy-to-follow tutorials/links for setting up the configuration you suggest? many thanks!

Comment: @DanieleB take a look at some 'microframeworks' for wsgi. if you don't need dynamic contents just follow some of their tutorials for 'hello world', like http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Comment: it looks like `sys.path.insert(0, current_path)` keeps adding the path each time the script is executed

Comment: a friend just mentioned to install this:
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments
how does it compare to flask?

Comment: @DanieleB well, quick fix would be `if current_path not in sys.path: sys.path.insert(0, current_path)`.

Comment: @DanieleB virtualenv is a tool for python to isolate your environment. mod_wsgi is a server module for apache to execute python scripts as wsgi server. flask is a framework for wsgi. it's like comparing apples to oranges. I have an apache server with mod_wsgi, that runs a flask web app which has its own virtualenv.

Comment: I am bit confused now :-)  so, to simplify my life is it enough to install flask or I also need virtualenv?

Comment: does flask compare to django?

Comment: I can't say about django, because I didn't used it as thoroughly as I did with flask. for simple life just use cgi script and learn frameworks later :D

Answer (score 1):

> I am importing a script trainstate.py which is in the same directory of the script I am running

This doesn't mean that this directory is the current working directory for your webserver process, not that it's in the sys.path for this process. thkang already provided the best possible answers (in reverse order should I say ), but anyway - try with this code instead and see what you get:

```
import sys, os
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

print "sys.path is : ", ", ".join(sys.path)
print "current working directory is : ", os.getcwd()

try: 
    # star imports are evil
    from trainstate import TrainState
except Exception, e:
    print "failed to import TrainState : %s" % e
else: 
    st = TrainState(784)
    print st.get_state()
```

Comment: I found out that if I call the script from the command line sys.path includes my current directory, if I call it from the browser the current directory is not in sys.path